# SSL Medium Strength Cipher Suites Supported (SWEET32) vulnerability of https in RHEL

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl

Just got a result from the Tenable Nessus scan and it showed that a RHEL 7.5 host is vulnerable to plugin 42873: "SSL Medium Strength Cipher Suites Supported (SWEET32)", on TCP port 443.

The Tenable Nessus report stated details about it below:

```
Medium Strength Ciphers (> 64-bit and < 112-bit key, or 3DES)

    Name                          Code             KEX           Auth     Encryption             MAC
    ----------------------        ----------       ---           ----     ---------------------  ---
    EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA          0x00, 0x16       DH            RSA      3DES-CBC(168)          SHA1
    ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA        0xC0, 0x12       ECDH          RSA      3DES-CBC(168)          SHA1
    DES-CBC3-SHA                  0x00, 0x0A       RSA           RSA      3DES-CBC(168)          SHA1

The fields above are :

  {Tenable ciphername}
  {Cipher ID code}
  Kex={key exchange}
  Auth={authentication}
  Encrypt={symmetric encryption method}
  MAC={message authentication code}
  {export flag}
```

So I check this host with command "netstat -tulnp" to get the source, as shown below:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      67529/httpd
```

And the output of "ps 67529" said the target was from here:

```
   PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 67529 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

The version of httpd is listed below, acquired from "httpd -v":

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
```

In order to solve this vulnerability, I edited /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf file and assured the following parameters do exist, and eventually restart the httpd to apply changes:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

However, after using Tenable Nessus scan again, the report still showed this vulnerability plugin 42873!!
Can anyone help please? Not sure which place should be edited to deal with the ssl-cipher stuff.

Thanks for any hint if there is.

Comment: your *"3DES"* enables the very ciphers you see (...DES-CBC3...)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for the hint~! should i just remove "3DES" and every will be right? or it is suggested to add other parameters?

Comment: Please follow the recommendations on how to configure the server  - see https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I edited the content of "SSLCipherSuite" with following:

`ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`

and changed "SSLHonorCipherOrder" to `off`.

The issue solved.

Thanks to @Steffen Ullrich's hints!!!